# Как изменить стили в wordpress на определенных страницах?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть блок на сайте, который хочу, чтобы появлялся всегда за исключением нескольких страниц, т.е. нужно его скрыть на определенных страницах. 
Пытаюсь записать такую конструкцию в файле **functions.php**, если вставить теги html, то они работают, а вот если стили, то нет.. Как же это можно решить без скриптов и плагинов?

```
<span class="conversion">блок, который нужно скрыть</span>
if ((!is_page('44')) || (!is_page('57'))) { 
?>
<style type="text/css">
.conversion {
  display:none;
}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: почему в файле functions.php, а не single.php?

Comment: @alenkins потому что для `single.php` даже `html` теги не отрабатывают..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю, зачем вы что-то делаете в functions.php.

На мой взгляд, правильный путь - сделать специальный шаблон для отображения указанных страниц. Сделать это можно двумя путями:

1. Если уникальная страница одна, копируете в директории темы файл `page.php` в `page-{id}.php`, где вместо `{id}` подставляете ID страницы.
2. Наиболее удачный вариант. Копируете `page.php` с любым удобным именем, которое будет понятно для вас идентифицировать новый шаблон (например `template-contacts.php`). Внутри этого файла вставляете вот такой комментарий: `<?php /* Template Name: Страница контактов */ ?>` (естественно вместо фразы "страницы контактов" можете написать что-то свое). После этого в редакторе контента страницы можно будет выбрать данный шаблон для любой нужной вам страницы.

После этого изменяете верстку нового шаблона так как вам необходимо.

Материал по данной теме:

1. [Создание собственных шаблонов страниц](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.88.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.86)
2. [3 способа создать шаблон страницы](http://wp-kama.ru/id_5177/3-sposoba-sozdat-shablon-stranitsyi.html)

**Дополнено**

Если хотите принципиально какой-то блок спрятать при помощи стилей, то можете учитывать, что обычно в тег `body` большинство тем добавляют класс вида `page-id-{id}`. Таким образом вы можете добавить в конец файла стилей такое правило:

```
.page-id-44 .conversion,
.page-id-57 .conversion {
    display: none;
}
```

PS. Не трогайте `functions.php` без необходимости. Как таковой верстки там быть не должно.

Comment: затык в том, что блок (условный баннер) берется не из шаблона страницы `page.php`. неужели нет варианта скрыть блок проще? - мне просто непонятно почему вдруг стандартный тег `style`  не отрабатывает или он перекрывается файлом `style.css`

Comment: Уточнения вопроса лучше добавляйте в текст вопроса. Насчет того, откуда берется блок вы ведь ничего не написали и пока вы этого не сделаете здесь врядли смогут догадаться как решить вашу проблему

Comment: нашел решение! не сразу заметил, что стиль создается, но с рангом низшим по важности, чем у `style.css`, что не очень очевидно, т.к. тег `style` в индексном файле всегда выше. добавил `inportant` - заработало!